# Seeking Crime Analysis Solution Tools in QGIS

Tags: kernel-density, crimestat

I want to create similar maps like shown at the bottom but I am "limited" to QGIS only right now.
My goal is to compare crimes committed in 2019 to those in 2020 in the same date window of quarantine.
ArcGIS Pro has solution for making the analysis of crime data easier called the Crime Analysis Solution.
How can i achieve similar results (maps) using QGIS?

"Using the **Density Change Tool** that is a part of the Crime Analysis Solution ribbon, I am able to compare the density raster of a current period to that of another period, essentially working as a raster calculator. The output shows the change between the two with areas in red being higher in change and areas in blue being lower in change"

"The **Percent Change Tool** in the Crime Analysis Solution ribbon creates a spatial join of point features (incidents) to polygon features (neighborhood boundaries, beats, precincts etc.) and compares two periods of time. The output is a layer showing areas of higher change in red and negative change in blue."

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The workflow would go something like this:

1. Use the Create Grid tool to create a uniform grid for your study area. You'll need to try a few different grid sizes to find the right fit.
2. Spatial Join 2019 Points to your grid
3. Spatial Join 2020 Points to your grid
4. Attribute join the 2 grids above and calculate the percent difference:
   100*(2020-2019)/2019
5. Use Rasterize tool (gdal toolbox) to convert your grid to a raster image
6. Use gaussian filter (saga toolbox) to fuzzy up your edges of your rasterized grid
7. In layer properties -> symbology, choose single band psuedocolor, pick your gradient, and at the bottom choose the option for bilinear resampling

There's lots of variables and different things to play with, but this is the way I make the above type maps without going bankrupt.

Comment: thank you very much !